# PDO changing database type to SQLITE throws error

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, pdo

I have this database class, when I' am using Database Type as "**mysql**" everything works fine but changing from "**mysql**" to "**sqlite**" throws error on the page.

**Here is the error message**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: users' in E:\xampp\htdocs\projects\test\pdo\database.php:33 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\projects\test\pdo\index.php(3): db->select('SELECT * FROM u...') #1 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\projects\test\pdo\database.php on line 33
```

**This is the complete Class Code.**

```
class db{
    public $isConnected;
    protected $datab;

    /* Database Object */
    public function __construct($username, $password, $host, $dbname, $options=array()){
        $this->isConnected = true;
        try { 
            $this->datab = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
            $this->datab->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
            $this->datab->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } 
        catch(PDOException $e) { 
            $this->isConnected = false;
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /* Disconnect from the database */
    public function disconnect(){
        $this->datab = null;
        $this->isConnected = false;
    }

    /* Select Query Against the Database */
    public function select($query, $params=array()){
            try{ 
                $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query); 
                $stmt->execute($params);
                return $stmt->fetchAll();       
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }       
    }

    /* Insert Query Against the Database */
    public function insert($query, $params){
            try{ 
                $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query); 
                $stmt->execute($params);
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }           
    }

    /* Update Query Against the Database */
    public function update($query, $params){
            return $this->insert($query, $params);
    }

    /* Delete Query Against the Database */
    public function delete($query, $params){
            return $this->insert($query, $params);
    }
}
$db = new db("root", "", "localhost", "test", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
```

Comment: What about those `MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` and `"localhost"`? SQLite does not work that way.

Comment: Hate to ask the obvious - but do you have a table called users in your sqlite db? If so, then surely "$this->datab = new PDO("mysql:host" would not want mysql:host??

Comment: Yes, the table does exists.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by commenting out the pdo sqlite extensions on XAMPP.